# Show that the solution of the Cauchy problem $y'(t)=e^{-y^2}+\arctan|t|$ with $y(0)=0$ is odd

Tags: real-analysis

I have the ODE $y'(t)=e^{-y^2}+\arctan|t|$ with the condition $y(0)=0$.
How can I prove the solution is odd?

Comment: Find a differential equation for $z(t) = -y(-t)$.

Comment: how can I prove te solution is unique on R?

Comment: By showing that the derivative of $e^{-y^2}$ is bounded.

Comment: You should know some uniqueness theorem for solutions of ODEs. Does that apply here?

Comment: $|f(t,y)| \le 1+\pi/2$ so for the sublinearity the solution exists unique on R?

Comment: how can I calculate $lim_{t->+\infty} y(t)$?